# Is an image of a continuous bijection from an open set open in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, functions, continuity

Is the following statement  true？

> Let $U,V \subset R^n$ and let $f:U \to V$ be a continuous bijection. If $U$ is an open set in the topology induced by the Euclidean norm, then $V$ is also an open set.

I think, it has something to do with the fact that preimage of any open set under $f$ is open too (one of the equivalent definitions of continuity). However, it also has to do with some specific topological properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$, as the generalization of this statement to the arbitrary topological space is clearly false (take the Sierpinski space $(\{0, 1\}, \{\emptyset , \{1\}, \{0, 1\}\}$ and function $f(x)$ that maps $1$ to $0$, and thus is a continuous bijection of two one-element sets)

Comment: This is true, but the proof is non-trivial.  Here's a reference:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain.

Comment: A proof can be found on page 126 of Allan Hatcher's book "Algebraic Topology", which is available for free on his website:  http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: A different proof (using an analytic approach to the mapping degree) can be found in "Nonlinear functional analysis" by Deimling. Yet another source is https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/brouwers-fixed-point-and-invariance-of-domain-theorems-and-hilberts-fifth-problem/

Comment: @Saito:  No problem!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956753/a-valid-proof-for-the-invariance-of-domain-theorem, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475933/is-there-some-elementary-proof-of-invariance-of-domain and many other posts. It is known as "invariance of domain".